# Search & Replace several Names in a .CSV File using Python

Tags: python, csv, search, replace

i've wrote a code that solves the task, but i doesnt feel well. It is like hit a nail in the wall using a stone instead a hammer.

The Task:

I scrape data from two different Sites using python with gets me two .CSV Files (thx to SIM) and now i want to compare the data. The problem is, that the Site i get the data from, are calling some names different e.g.

`Chelsea FC` instead `FC Chelsea` or `FSV Mainz` instead `1. FSV Mainz 05` and many more names i have to replace.

Here is the code i made:

```
text = open("input.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("Chelsea FC", "FC Chelsea")
x = open("output1.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()

text = open("output1.csv", "r")
text = ''.join([i for i in text]) \
    .replace("FSV Mainz", "1. FSV Mainz 05")
x = open("output_final.csv","w")
x.writelines(text)
x.close()
```

The Problem is that i have to write a file after every single name i have changed. I mean it does the Job but it hurts my feelings.

Can you guide me the way to better code, please? Attention: I am an absolute beginner!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you use libraries like pandas?

Comment: i guess... i mean i could but i dont know how... but hylowaker told me how :) thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one simple way to do

```py
with open("input.csv", "r") as file:
    text = file.read()

text = text.replace("Chelsea FC", "FC Chelsea")
text = text.replace("FSV Mainz", "1. FSV Mainz 05")
# more replaces...

with open("output_final.csv", "w") as x:
    x.write(text)
```

For more complex text manipulation, try using `re`(regular expression) module

Comment: nice! thank you very much! I think this simple manipulation is enough for my task! Thank you! Thank you!